# What is "disclosure" in the work of Simone DeBeauvoir

Tags: existentialism

I'm reading The Ethics of Ambiguity and she's constantly referring to this concept of "disclosure". "Being discloses itself" is a recurring phrase. "another way of disclosing the world." is another instance.

What is "disclosure" in this context?

Comment: This seems to be an immediate reference to Heidegger's thought, and really it is grounded in phenomenology. I have never read any of her work, but this was not hard to find:  https://books.google.com/books?id=FjJ_kQCNwogC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=de+beauvoir+heidegger+%22disclosure%22&source=bl&ots=8yZ1fXXAzO&sig=Oc09o9fOHy5aT8_yNAEDhCcXc4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrlZv-26_aAhUNWN8KHRh0A2IQ6AEwA3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=de%20beauvoir%20heidegger%20%22disclosure%22&f=false  Most larger U.S. libraries should have this book, even the local public library may have it.

Comment: I saw somewhere else she believed that science does not fully disclose being; I am sure Heidegger and Gadamer would agree with her, and not just them, but other philosophers too. P.S. The book I linked to above was the Cambridge Companion to Simone De Beauvoir.

Comment: Linked to Sartre's concept of [disclosure of being (and meaning)](https://books.google.it/books?id=L6igUcpDEO8C&pg=PA39). See also [The Ethics of Ambiguity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/beauvoir/#EthAmbBadFaiAppArt).